# access referenced images model from projects model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have made 2 models:

[Project model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxtk2.png)

[Image model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kuVb.png)

i want to display image gallery for each project, i have made a foreign key in images table that references projects table and i want to access all the images for a specific project and display it in mi view

here are the pictures of mi db tables:

[Images table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Bkv.png)

[Project table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0mp7.png)

controller code:

[ProjekatController image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8vZZ.png)

[view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMh3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Projeketcontrolller` just replace line

```
`Projekat::findOrFail($id)->images`;
```

to

> show images by project id......

```
Projekat::findOrFail($id);
```

and in view replace line

```
{{$proj->image->image}}
```

to

```
{{$proj->images->image}}
```

after  your `projekat model` look like this

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(image::class,'projekat_id','id');
    }
```

and your `image model` look like this

```
 protected $fillable = ['projekat_id','image'];
    public function Projekat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Projekat::class,'id','projekat_id');
    }
```

Comment: i am getting a trying to get property 'images' of non-object error

Comment: first u read this article and try first https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many if not done then i am always help with u

Comment: problem still remains, i correctly defined the relationships and it just seem that it can not find the images object, i am   getting this error Trying to get property 'images' of non-object

Comment: i added chenged Projekat::findOrFail($id); to Projekat::findOrFail($id)->get(); and now i get a Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance error

Comment: `Projekat::find($id);`  only used `find` method

Comment: @NikolaGrujicic check i update `image` model in my answer

Comment: i solved it, i had to iterate with 2 foreach loops but now i get same 2 pictures on evry project, how can i display the pictures based on project_id?

Comment: @NikolaGrujicic pl create chat room so we can discuss

Comment: could you please invite me to a chat room, i don't now how to do it

Comment: could you please invite me to a chat room, i don't now how to do it

Comment: it seems that i can not chat because i don't have enough point, good news is i solved the problem i just had to use eager loading, thnx very much for your support it helpped me a loth